# Bootstrap Multiselect - How to access value I just selected?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following

```
<select name="department" id="department-list" class="form-control" onChange="getTeams3(this.value);" multiple>
  <option value="MONGOOSEAHOY" selected>All departments</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The function is

```
function getTeams3(val) {
    console.log($('#department-list').val());
    console.log(val);
```

However - the 2nd line shows the value I just selected, instead if I select 1,2 and 3, it will just show 1. If I choose 2 and then 3, it will just show 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: `evt.currentTarget.value`?

Answer (score -1):

Since it's a multiple select, you can 'change' more than one element at once by holding shift and pressing on 2 or 3, for example. So in that case, what would you expect in 'val'? It would only make sense if it could be an array of values, not just a single value.

I don't think you've any option except to hold an array of currently-selected values (`var cachedVals = $('#department-list').val()`) somewhere, initialised on page load.

Then, when your `getTeams3()` is called on change, get `var newVals = $('#department-list').val()` again and compare against `cachedVals`*-

- the values in newVals but not in cachedVals were just added;
- if none, then the values in cachedVals but not in newVals were just removed.

Don't forget to set `cachedVals = newVals;` before returning from the function, of course.

- For array comparison, I'd use the Underscore.js library - some very handy functions, e.g.

  _.difference(['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '3']);

returns

['2']

Comment: The heroic silent downvoter strikes. Please comment at least.